# aab format return an apk without armeabi_v7a library under 32 bit devices

Tags: android, delphi, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

Deploying my android 64 bit app + android 32 bit app (made in Delphi) in aab format (Android App Bundles) under google play not work under android 32 bit devices. When i start the app it's say that their is no so librairies and failed to start (my app is build inside an SO library). when I use apk extractor (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui&hl=en) to extract the apk of the installed app i see also that their is no SO libray inside  (not even the armeabi_v7a directory). when i explore the aab file with App Bundles explorer i can see that for my android 32 bit device i have this zip file that contain :

```
1/ base.apk (4Mo) without any libraries inside (the apk I extract for my app with apk extractor)
2/ config.armeabi_v7a.apk (14Mo) with libraries inside (so they are here in a different apk?)
3/ config.en.apk (20 ko)
4/ config.xhdpi.apk (110 ko)
```

Also When I download the app from google play store, I see the progress bar is growing still 22% and then it's stop and the install of the app start (don't know if it's matter, i try on 2 differents devices)

[image]

any idea what wrong? Note: on android 64 devices it's seam to work

one remark, I try to check the aab with bundletool and i find that the extracted apks is

- for android 64: base-arm64_v8a.apk : 72Mo (libapp.so is 64 Mo)
- for android 32: base-armeabi_v7a.apk : 14 Mo (libapp.so is 46 Mo)
  so i don't understand why only 14 Mo on base-armeabi_v7a.apk (or why 64 Mo on base-arm64_v8a.apk)

Comment: How are you creating the deployment? From the IDE? Command-line? Have you checked the Deployment Manager to see if the .so is being deployed?

Comment: @DaveNottage from the command line. the so (both 64Bit and 32 bit) are in the aab i can see it

Comment: Do you use the NativeActivity?

Comment: Has the project a . in its name? We have another report that this is causing trouble in the deployment script -- in the short term you'd have to use the native tools manually (as I guess you cannot change the app name)

Comment: @MarcoCantù thanks, I just found the problem and get the solution here in case someone else encounter it too

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found the problem! It's because ih my settings I have for the ndk:

> C:\SDKs\android-ndk-r17b\platforms\android-28
>
> C:\SDKs\android-ndk-r17b\platforms\android-28\arch-arm\usr\lib
>
> C:\SDKs\android-ndk-r17b\platforms\android-28\arch-arm\usr\lib;C:\SDKs\android-ndk-r17b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a

in in short I have `android-28` instead of `android-22`

This settings was working perfectly on 10.3.2 of Delphi but when I update to 10.3.3 this make the problem I encountered:

- compilation for android32 and android64 work well, running on android64 devices (android32 app or android64 app) work well too
- compilation for android32 work well, but running on android32 devices failed !

I didn't detect the problem before to go in production because I made the test of the app (android32 and android64) on my android 64 devices :(

the worse was that google play didn't detect that the library was broken and accept the package, and immediately upload it to all the devices who have my app installed. and no way to roll back, i must absolutely provide a new binary but it's took me some time to understand where the problem was because i didn't have anymore the 10.3.2 in my computer as their is no way to have 10.3.2 and 10.3.3 on the same computer.

**conclusion**: installing a minor update of delphi is not totally risk free, and don't trust google play to warn you if your package is broken, make strong test before to deploy